# Python - Date Format

Tags: python, date, datetime, string-formatting

I have the code below that returns the date in the following format: m/d/yyyy, but I would like it to return it as mm/dd/yy( So it would show a 0- before single digit dates and only show the last two digits of the year). How can I tweak it so?

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
'{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}'.format(today)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

You can find a list of directives [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Or equivalently, if using `format` as above, `{0:%m/%d/%y}.format(today)`

Comment: Hey, that's cool. I didn't know you could do that with the new format syntax!

Comment: @  donkopotamus  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
'{0:%m%d%y}'.format(today).format(today)
```

returns: '052818'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program that gets you the output that you are seeking:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

now = now.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
print(now)
```

We can use the strftime method to format the date. We pass the lowercase m (%m) because this will get return the month with a 0 in front of it. The lower case %d will also pass a day, and the lowercase %y will pass a year, only showing the last two digits as you specified

Here is your output:

```
05/28/18
```

And if you work with a day in the single digits, you get the 0 in front of the day that you wanted:

```
05/03/18
```